# How to install latest stable Chrome (34) on Ubuntu?

Tags: updates, google-chrome, update-manager

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64bit) and am trying to install the latest version of Chrome (not Chromium).

Currently I have Chrome 30.0.1599.114 installed. I'm following the instructions on this [page](http://gamblisfx.com/how-to-install-google-chrome-34-0-on-xubuntu-14-04/) trying:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

which works without errors - as does:

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

but both times I'm ending up with `Chrome 30.0.1599.114` and I'm too Ubuntu-novice to do anything about it...

Any ideas?

Comment: Since it's goole who maintains that repository either contact with them or wait until they 'fix it'.

Comment: That would clarify things...

Comment: The instructions you're following are for 14.04, not 12.04 which you currently have installed. Might be time to upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the Chrome ppa added and Chrome installed use

```
    sudo apt-get upgrade google-chrome-stable
```